# click on autocompletetextview suggested item

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

i have an AutoCompleteTextView and when i type suggest some results for me. My question is, how i can select and click on first suggestion with clicking on keyboard enter button? i don't want click on result. I want when user click on enter button on keyboard cliclistener of AutoCompleteTextView called and tap on first item!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be an easy job

```
private AutoCompleteTextView mUrlEditText;
mUrlEditText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.UrlText);
mUrlEditText.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
        /* do something */
    }
});
```